# Stored procedure return into DataSet in C# .Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, stored-procedures, dataset

I want to return virtual table from stored procedure and I want to use it in dataset in c# .net. My procedure is a little complex and can't find how to return a table and set it in a dataset

Here is my procedure to modify:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Procedure1] 

    @Start datetime, 
    @Finish datetime,
    @TimeRange time
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    declare @TimeRanges as TABLE (SessionStart datetime, SessionEnd datetime);

     with TimeRanges as (
  select @Start as StartTime, @Start + @TimeRange as EndTime
  union all
  select StartTime + @TimeRange, EndTime + @TimeRange
    from TimeRanges
    where StartTime < @Finish )
  select StartTime, EndTime, Count( Test.ScenarioID ) as TotalPeaks
    from TimeRanges as TR left outer join
      dbo.Test as Test on TR.StartTime <= Test.SessionStartTime and Test.SessionCloseTime < TR.EndTime
    group by TR.StartTime, TR.EndTime   
END
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Try this

```
    DataSet ds = new DataSet("TimeRanges");
    using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("ConnectionString"))
    {               
            SqlCommand sqlComm = new SqlCommand("Procedure1", conn);               
            sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Start", StartTime);
            sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Finish", FinishTime);
            sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TimeRange", TimeRange);

            sqlComm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            da.SelectCommand = sqlComm;

            da.Fill(ds);
     }
```

Comment: One thing that got me when trying to use this answer was that i had to set my command type to `CommandType.StoredProcedure`. so it would look like this `sqlComm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure`.

Comment: no problem. I sat and struggled with it for an hour or so before I googled it and found the [MS article that gave me the missing piece](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310070). But this certainly got me 99.9% of the way there. Great answer.

Comment: @codingbiz How if t sql return output param beside datatable, too? Is it possible to get it too? How? sample?

Comment: `ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0]` to get first column of first row, since you only have one row and one column

Comment: Output parameter is used when inserting... this is a select query method

Answer (score 8):

I should tell you the basic steps and rest depends upon your own effort. You need to perform following steps.

- Create a connection string.
- Create a SQL connection
- Create SQL command
- Create SQL data adapter
- fill your dataset.

Do not forget to open and close connection. follow this [link](http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqldataadapter) for more under standing.

Comment: as answers go I don't think this was very helpful. Unless otherwise stated I feel that people want specifics rather than generics.

Answer (score 4):

You can declare `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` instances at global level so that you can use it through out the class. Connection string is in `Web.Config`.

```
SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SqlConnector"].ConnectionString);
SqlCommand sqlcomm = new SqlCommand();
```

Now you can use the below method to pass values to **Stored Procedure** and get the `DataSet`.

```
public DataSet GetDataSet(string paramValue)
{
    sqlcomm.Connection = sqlConn;
    using (sqlConn)
    {
        try
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter())
            {  
                // This will be your input parameter and its value
                sqlcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ParameterName", paramValue);

                // You can retrieve values of `output` variables
                var returnParam = new SqlParameter
                {
                    ParameterName = "@Error",
                    Direction = ParameterDirection.Output,
                    Size = 1000
                };
                sqlcomm.Parameters.Add(returnParam);
                // Name of stored procedure
                sqlcomm.CommandText = "StoredProcedureName";
                da.SelectCommand = sqlcomm;
                da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds);                            
            }
        }
        catch (SQLException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("SQL Error: " + ex.Message);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e.Message);
        }
    }
    return new DataSet();
}
```

The following is the sample of connection string in config file

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="SqlConnector"
         connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=YourDatabaseName;User id=YourUserName;Password=YourPassword"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: No, you should always create SqlCommand and SqlConnection objects just as you use them, inside `using` statements so they’re disposed afterwards and to ensure they’re not used by multiple threads.

Comment: Since SqlCommand and SqlConnection are used in global level for multiple methods as well (for reuse purpose), I have neither used `using` nor any command to dispose. Ideally, I used to dispose this wherever necessary/application ends. Also, please be noted that I have not mentioned the complete code from the program as my intention was to answer for what OP asked. That's the reason you are not seeing any code for disposal @Rory

Comment: What I'm saying is that it's best practice to NOT do what you're suggesting. Your example should not be followed. There's no good reason to keep a SqlCommand or SqlConnection object beyond when you're using it directly, and there's lots of downsides (e.g. use by multiple threads, not disposing properly, preventing efficient connection pooling, keeping more connections open than needed).

Comment: Also it looks like there's a few bugs in `GetDataSet()`, e.g. it always returns a new empty `DataSet` object, it disposes the `sqlconn` variable after it executes the first time. Here's a good example of filling a DataSet from a proc https://stackoverflow.com/a/12974098/8479