# Call in stored procedure error with SQL server in C#

Tags: c#, database, sql-server-2005

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Stored procedure return into DataSet in C# .Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12973773/stored-procedure-return-into-dataset-in-c-sharp-net)

How can I call a stored procedure from my project using C#? I need to get the output of that stored procedure into a data table but I'm getting an error.

**Code:**

```
private string connectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Persist Security Info=False;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=blablalbla;";
    private DataTable dtProductPrijsActueel = new DataTable();
    public DataTable productPrijsActueel()
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand comm = conn.CreateCommand();
        comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        comm.CommandText = "procSelectPrijsActueel";

        dtProductPrijsActueel.Load(comm.ExecuteReader());
        conn.Close();
        conn.Dispose();

        return dtProductPrijsActueel;
    }
```

**Error:**

```
ERROR : KEYWORD NOT SUPPORTED : 'PROVIDER'
```

Comment: You need to show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: The usual way, you just set the `SqlCommand` object's `CommandType` property to `StoredProcedure`.

Comment: There are so much documentation around, you could try searching first, and then come back with specific code / questions when you have a problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is *really* something that should've just been googled, but the general code you're looking for looks something like this:

```
  string connect = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["conn"];
  SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connect);
  string spName = "TheSpName";

  SqlCommand spCmd = new SqlCommand(spName, connection);
  spCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

  spCmd.Parameters.Add("@SomeParam", SqlDbType.String).Value = "Some Parameter";

  connection.Open();

  var dataTableReader = spCmd.ExecuteReader();
```