# How to read the value from Pivot table Coloumns using DataReader or DataSet class

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, ado.net

Here is my Store Procedure and my question is how to read the columns value in DataReader or DataSet.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE StudentProgressReport   
BEGIN   
    SET NOCOUNT ON;  

DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(r.Exam_Date) 
    FROM Institute_Student_Results r
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT Student_Roll_No,Student_First_Name,Student_Last_Name,' + @cols + ' from 
        (
            select distinct  u.Student_Roll_No,
            s.Student_First_Name,s.Student_Last_Name,               
            u.Marks,e.Examination_Total_Marks,
            u.Exam_Date

            from Institute_Student_Results u

            inner join Institute_Examinations e
            on u.Exam_ID=e.Institute_Examination_ID

            inner join Student_Master s
            on u.Student_ID=s.Student_ID

            where e.Institute_Course_Batch_ID=110
            and u.Exam_ID=105
            and u.Marks is not null             

       ) x
        pivot 
        (
            MAX(Marks)
            for Exam_Date in (' + @cols + ')
        ) p '

   execute(@query)     

END
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use SqlDataAdapter to execute the stored procedure and fill a DataSet with the results.  See this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12974098/1339616) for an example of populating a DataSet or this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3528647/1339616) for populating a DataTable.